# Even after successful running , my angular component is not being included in my angular module

Tags: angular, module, components

I tried to run ng generate component elements/ElementsHome , where elements is my module inside which I was trying to create the component ElementsHome . The run was successful but in the terminal the Updated file path was not created as a hyperlink. It is showing that the component is not created inside the module , how to fix this issue. The error is encircled in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Can you check whether the component name is available in app.module.ts or if you are having elements module means check that module element.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command does not work.
What you should do is move to the directory elements using

`cd src/app/elements`

And run

`ng generate ElementsHome`

Now, the component will be added  to the module automatically

Answer (score 0):

check if you had imported this in your app.module.ts
**app.module.ts**

```
import { ElementsHomeComponent } from './elements-home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ElementsHomeComponent ,
 ],
})
```